# Pivoting tuples in pandas DataFrame until specific row element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert a simple tuple[2] dataset to a usable format with pandas. I will use an example of a user dataset.

My input looks as follows:

```
properties, value
username, 1 
email, 2 
created, 3 
username, 4 
email, 5 
created, 6
```

Every time 'username' appears in the first column, the tuples below that belong to that user. I am trying to convert this to a format where each user is listed on a single row, with the properties in columns.

Desired output:

```
username, email, created
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

I have the input file loaded into a pandas dataframe *df*:

```
with open('input.csv', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=" :", engine='python', header=None, parse_dates=True)
```

Then I figured I would use the *pivot* function, but I am receiving the following error which I am unsure how to resolve:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Could anyone help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming the username, email and created are list objects. Whenever an user is created, same index of every list is fulfilled.

```py
username = list()
email = list()
created = list()

# Add some elements for first user
username.append('1')
email.append('2')
created.append('3')

# Add some elements for second user
username.append('4')
email.append('5')
created.append('6')
```

Then, all you need to do is create columns with name of your lists and put data correctly.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(username, email, created)), columns=['Username', 'Email', 'Created'])

# Printing without indexes
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Result of printing DataFrame would be:

```py
Username Email Created
       1      2       3
       4      5       6
```